# Is it legit if the autors of the worst received answers vote for close?

Tags: discussion, moderation, questions, close-reasons, users

My Question is on Hold to close now for "Off-Topic".
It has 43 Upvotes, 16 favourites and 20 answers.
Before i edited the question one might have thought it could be a question for a mind-hack.

So i edited my question to clarify that I'm **not** looking for mindhacks only.

Anyway the users with the worst received answers (-3 and -1 Score) **rage-closevoted** obviously my question. How can it be that someone actually *answers* a question and then requests a *close*?! If I think a question is Off-Topic, would I really anser? No!

Here I really think the moderation privileges are badly abused.

Is there any instance on stackexchange who handles cases of moderation abuses?

Answer (score 9):

I can understand your concern, but as a systemic ongoing problem, I think it's a bit of a stretch to draw that correlation widely — that someone whose answer has been down-voted is more inclined to (or should be prevented from) closing the question itself.

But an issue I *have* seen is users *knowingly* answering questions they know are going to get closed (even voting to do so themselves).  **I would urge folks to *resist* that temptation** to quickly answer a question before it gets closed. I know you are just trying to help, but it creates a situation where onlookers realize they can ask anything they want because they'll inevitably get an answer… yet it creates a bit of minutia that can never be *properly* answered because it was deemed off topic on that site.

It creates the *worst* of both possible worlds.

Regarding the question itself: It *does* seem to fall on the wrong side of that "no mind hacks" line. Rather than stating that physical solutions okay too, you *could* have asked the question whether there are any tools/alarm clocks that would force you out of that habit. It would render most of the answers invalid, but that is part of why mind hacks are somewhat troublesome; they tend to lead to a lot of sharing of anecdotes and strings of questions/answers that become somewhat repetitive running on a few basic themes. But that assertion is outside the scope of *this* post.

Comment: Well there is no proof for this, but such behavior really takes me away from this stack exchange. I don't like those toxic moderations. Also if you all want to make *Life Hacks* more attractive, I don't know why you vote to close one of the highest voted and most read questions here. That makes no sense.

Comment: @OttoV. because it is off topic?Being highly upvoted/viewed does not make an otherwise off topic question on topic.

Comment: @Dragonrage but it literaly means alot of people are interested in it *while they are browsing this exchange*. If you care more about *unclear* off-topic than helping/informing users it's really sad.

Comment: 1. I was the one who started the whole closure of your question, I was the first VTC, I urged users to vote as such cause regardless of how well received the question was, it didn't make it any less off-topic. You can check chat, and @Robert can confirm it seeing the deleted comments in the thread.

Comment: 2. @OttoV. The issue here is clearly stated by the answer, users with enough experience in the site, still answer the question knowing it will probably get closed, that's the real issue here, not the modding privileges. And you can tell who they are, cause they VTC yet they provided an answer for the question.

Comment: 3. We are all about helping/informing users, as long as it follows the site's guidelines, that's why we have rules. The sad part here is that you think you can ask whatever you want with no respect nor giving importance of the site's guidelines and get an answer just cause you want us to answer. @OttoV.